# Third party ad loaded Modernizr conflicting with own copy

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr, ads

I'm developing a website for a company and sometimes advertisements appear on it. 
The problem is I load Modernizr in order to do some javascript code depending on whether we are on mobile, Ipad or desktop. One of the ads we display loads Modernizr too and their Modernizr is generating a conflict with mine breaking my javascript by causing the "Modernizr.mq" to return undefined into the terminal.

I don't know how to resolve that and the advertising company won't do anything with their Modernizr ...

Comment: Sounds like pretty bad advertiser code in that case. there is not much you can do other than not use that add network. You could write a smaller loader which would only load in your version of modernizr if none is detected.

Comment: Sure, I don't know why advertisers use external library because theirs customers can use the same library and make it crash like my case..
why not, I don't really know how Modernizr works because a colleague did this and he left the company.

But it would be the solution, I tried to load Modernizr asynchronously but not worked anymore.

Comment: Please show your async attempt.

Comment: I just put a script tag with a "async" attribute like that : 
<script async scr="modernizr.js"></script> in order to load my Modernizr after Modernizr's advertiser but it not working because my main javascript needs Modernizr to works. So it is a bad solution. I could test if navigator is trying to load an other version of Modernizr like you tell before but I don't know how can I did this I'm not good with Modernizr =/

Comment: Try replacing your script tag for modernizr with `<script>window.Modernizr || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>` otherwise add `<script>window.Modernizr = undefined;</script>`

Comment: I finally tried an other solution which work. I set a timeout of 3 seconds and inside it an interval which test the type of Modernizr.mq, if it equals undefined I reload Modernizr with $.getScript and I clear the interval :)

Comment: 3 seconds might not be enough in some cases. Try executing this on window.load or some other event which is more reliable.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to change it, thank you for help guys ;)